# PHP preg_replace regex to remove last tag

Tags: php, regex

I'm having some trouble to make the following code to output what I expect:

```
<?php
$a='##foobar(a b, c d)@@f()</td>a</td>';
echo preg_replace('/foobar.*?\)(.*)\<\/td\>$/', 'blah(this)$1', $a);
```

The expected result should be `##blah(this)@@f()</td>a`, however its output is `##blah(this)@@f()a` (using [phptester](http://phptester.net/)).

It does not make sense to me how it outputs the last `a`, but not the previous `</td>` tag. I want to remove only the last `</td>` tag.

In my regex, I'm doing a greedy match `(.*)`, but I've also tried using `(.*?)`, which outputs the same result.

I'm escaping every special character. The special regular expression characters are: `. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -`.

Comment: The browser is processing the `</td>` as a tag, therefore it doesn't show up.

Comment: How are you checking your result? Because if you were outputing to a browser you wouldn't see the closing of the `<td>` element.

Comment: I have pointed out in my question that I'm using the phptester (with a link to it).

Comment: why not preg_replace('~</td>$~', '', $str) .. just woke up.. hope that's right haha

Comment: Because it is actually a more complex regex than that, I'm just having trouble with the last part of it though.

Comment: Regex doesn't work for html. Use a html parser instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is Ok, the problem is the browser that doesn't render the closing tag. Try this:

```
<?php
$a = '##foobar(a b, c d)@@f()</td>a</td>';
$b = preg_replace('/foobar.*?\)(.*)\<\/td\>$/', 'blah(this)$1', $a);

echo htmlentities($b);
```

Comment: **Notice:** You don't need the `htmlentities()` for whatever you're doing. It's just so you can see it in the browser for testing purposes only.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `phptester`, you can use PHP in interactive mode with the command line:

```
php -a
```

and then you enter in an interactive shell, very similar to python.

Testing your code with that tool, we can see that your regex is OK.

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $a='##foobar(a b, c d)@@f()</td>a</td>';
php > echo preg_replace('/foobar.*?\)(.*)\<\/td\>$/', 'blah(this)$1', $a);
##blah(this)@@f()</td>a
php >
```